# What is the abbreviation for "o.a.c.c.C" in the log?

Tags: spring-boot

What is the abbreviation for "o.a.c.c.C" in the log?

```
2023-08-02 07:46:18:933 as_ptum [http-nio-8080-exec-260] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost][175] [TxId : MD010084_22601^1689775506414^1668728 ， SpanId : 8020909055417331416]- Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0， location=/error] org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
```

In this logs, What are the meanings of "o.a.c.c.C", "Tomcat", and "localhost" in "o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]"?

Comment: I think that is not an abbreviation. It looks like the full name of the class. You can see the log template to verify this and change it to find out the class name.

Comment: It's probably an abbreviation for `org.apache.catalina....`. Catalina is the internal name for Tomcat. In Spring Boot applications, long names in the logging are often abbreviated in such a way. [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) is the embedded servlet container and HTTP server that runs inside your Spring Boot application. [`localhost`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-localhost/) is the hostname of the machine (your own computer) on which it runs.

Answer (score 3):

`o.a.c.c.C.` is an obrevation where each letter is the first letter in the package name and the last one 'C' is probably the first letter of a class name. So, as Jesper correctly said in the comment it is probably an observation for something like this:  `org.apache.catalina....`

Answer (score 0):

Michael Gantman and Jesper gave me an idea. I debugged the source code of Springboot, tracked and determined the print point of the log "o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext", through "this. context.getLogger().info(message)" method, found that the full name of "o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]" is "org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost]. [/]", the following is the corresponding screenshot.

[image]